What's the difference, if any, between "verser en pluie" and "verser lentement"?
What's the difference, if any, between "verser en pluie" and "verser lentement"?


Verser lentement describes the flow (the amount of product poured per unit of time is low) while verser en pluie describes how it is poured, in that case to as large a surface of the pan as possible.
You can verser en pluie relatively quickly if you move the bag fast enough and you can verser lentement but not en pluie if you don't move the bag at all.
In the couscous case it's probably wise to do both: lentement and en pluie.

Thank you! What's the difference, if any, between "verser en pluie" and "saupoudrer"?

La dernière phrase ne convient pas sur ce site consacré à la langue, plutôt qu'aux conseils culinaires ;-)

@Frank Les conseils culinaires sont consacrés à la langue.

@Frank Oui, ces conseils s'adressent aux papilles linguistiques !

@jlliagre Bon. Dans linquistique, il y a langue, avec au moins deux sens, je suppose ;-)

In my understanding, you could verser lentement but still in big batches (imagine holding a bag of flour slightly tipped).
En pluie though, you pour mainly small elements like a rain.
This way you keep the mix homogeneous and avoid forming grumeaux -the nigthmare of any well accomplished housewife ;-).

+1 because I don't want to take your English into account, I hope you will replace "housewife" by a more generic term (e.g., but cook can do the trick...)

@None 'housewife' est une blague en mode famille-parfaite-des-années-50.

Your answer doesn't read like a joke!
